# Select and return value with Plpgsql function

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, syntax, plpgsql

I'm having a problem with PLPGSQL function. The exercise required that I had to get value from column 'x'from test_table (x, param1, param2 are primary keys). If max 'x' is null then raise exception, else return its max value plus 1. I have my function below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test_get_x(
i_param1 varchar(64)
, i_param2 varchar(64)
, i_x int
)
    RETURNS int8
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
    max_x int8;
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(ttbl.x) AS max_x
    FROM test_table AS ttbl
    WHERE ttbl.param1 = i_param1
      AND ttbl.param2 = i_param2
      AND ttbl.x = i_x;

    IF max_x IS NULL THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'error';
    ELSE
        RETURN (max_x + 1);
    END IF;
END;
$$;
```

When I run test_get_x(i_param1, i_param2, i_x) with correct input, it always shows error like: "column 'i_param1' does not exist" or "Query does not specify where to return result data". I don't know if the function has any syntax error because the IDE does not notify about it and I had a struggling time learning about SQL and PLPGSQL function syntax.
Hope you guys can help me explain why the function above is wrong. Sorry for bad English and thanks for reading :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic syntax confusion: `AS max_x` defines an alias for the column, while `INTO max_x` specifies the variable where the result should be stored.